# What was Danny Rand's obsession with white shoes?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist

In *Iron Fist*, after Hogarth started his case, Danny Rand always wore white sporty shoes under his suit:

[image][image][image][image][image]

He always wore white shoes, except when he found the chemist and in tournament when he wore black shoes without the suit.

What was Danny Rand's obsession with wearing white shoes under the suit? Is it just a random character choice or is there some meaning behind it?

Comment: He wears white shoes when he is in his business suit, but outside of that we also see him wear grey and brown shoes e.g. when he lectures Colleen's students, when he is at Bakuto's compound or fights him and his men in the lobby, when he is on the run from the DEA, ...

Comment: So not only is it trivia, it's a question based on not paying attention to detail...

Comment: How is this trivia? It asks for the significance of a character's rather unusual attire.

Comment: @cde which details, kindly elaborate.

Comment: I think it's also possibly because he hasn't really had shoes since he was 10 years old - so to him white sneakers are appropriate wear for most anything.  He would have some kind of boots/wraps when he was in the snow, but other than that he's probably been barefoot for 15 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a character's choice (producers decision) related to the state of the scene he is doing.

You already pointed out in the question:

> He always wore white shoes, except when he found the chemist and in tournament when he wore black shoes without the suit.

It seems that he whore white shoes in casual and business environments, the shoes being **white** transpiring calm and relaxing environments.

And **black** when he was going into action, traspiring a more violent e serious environment.

[Colors scheme (tones)](https://www.cinema5d.com/film-color-schemes-cinematic-color-design/) are sometimes used in movies to explain and transpire emotions to the audience.

> Color can affect us psychologically and physically, often without us being aware, and can be used as a strong device within a story. Knowledge gives you control, and control means you can manipulate and use color to give your work a powerful and beautiful edge.
>
> Being able to use color to create harmony, or tension within a scene, or to bring attention to a key visual theme can be used to spectacular effect.

It also could be just preferences. I also wears a type of shoes in casual, business environments, and some other different shoes when doing hard work or exercising.

Answer (score 2):

While not removing any merit from Gustavo Gabriel's response, I also believe that the white shoes (that stand out in the scenes) also represent him standing out while in the company, or while having a simple dinner. On the other hand, the black shoes blend perfectly with his outfit while fighting.

This shows that he seems more in ease while in combat and less confortable (or standing out more) while trying to have a "regular life" or managing his company.